# 9-patch images not showing up

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nine-patch

I just generated some 9 patch images with

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

This outputs some subfolders of `drawable` like `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, etc.

I pasted them in the drawable folder and currently got multiple images in multiple folders.
However, when I want to use the image, it needs to be in the `drawable` folder as well (not any subfolders) otherwise Android Studio can't find the image.

Do I need to paste an hdpi (or something else?) 9 patch image into the drawable folder so it can find it and will the 9 patch images still work for multiple screen sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you put the density-specific folders (e.g. `drawable-hdpi`) *inside* the `drawable` folder. This is incorrect. The density-specific folders should be at the same level as the `drawable` folder.

For example:

```
├── app
    ├── main
        ├── res
            ├── drawable
            ├── drawable-mdpi
            ├── drawable-hdpi
```

The `drawable` folder is used for drawables that do not need density-specific variants.